# Rails scope to go 'up' a has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Imagine a message board where `User`s each `has_many` `Post`s.

I've got a scope that returns me a bunch of `Post`s, and what I'd like to do is go from there to a set of `User`s.

I could just iterate through, and for each `Post`, add its `User` to a relation, then dedupe the `User`s, but there must be an easier way, no?

Comment: Is this in your controller or view? Could you post your code?

Comment: Well, I've been writing it in my view but I don't imagine it would make a huge difference. So I want something like`Posts.where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.day).users` . . .

Comment: You really shouldn't have code like that in your view, it belongs in your controller. Also the association you just wrote should do what you're looking for

Comment: I agree -- was just quickly trying to hack around in the view before moving things to the controller, but anyway, that's beside the point. I'm seeing Posts.where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.day).users returning an empty array, while Posts.where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.day).first.user returns a User object. What's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join those two tables: In my example I'm assuming you want to get all the usernames that posted in the last 24 hours:

```
    # joining posts with users
Post.joins(:user)

    # filtering all posts that are older than 1 day
    .where("posts.created_at > ?", Time.now - 1.day)

    # selecting every user only once
    .select("users.id").uniq

    # then selecting the fields you want to work with
    .select("users.name")
```

Answer (score 1):

Posts.where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.day).map(&:user).uniq

The posts query will return a set of posts. You need to map these posts to a user, and then truncate the set to unique users (because a post may belong to the same user).

With eager loading:

Posts.where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.day).includes(:user).map(&:user).uniq

This way you won't have to make a query each time you try and fetch a user from a post.